# Considering two characters as one in a string

Tags: java

```
String secondLine = ...E......E..E.E;    
String failures = "E";    
String passed = ".";

int i = 0;
while ((i = (secondLine.indexOf(failures, i) + 1)) > 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
    feedbackString += "<strong style='color: red;'><li>Failed: </strong><strong>" + i + "</strong> - " + "out of " + resultString.length() + " tests.<br>";
}
```

The total number of the tests is the sum of the dots which is = 12. and the E's are the failures which in this case = 4.

The dots are the passes and the E's are the failures. Whenever this is ran and there is a failure, it adds an 'E' in front of the dot which becomes'.E'. I can get the E's on its own but I want a statement that says given a dot comes before the E and then it should print the '.E' and pass it into a variable called failedTest.

The code above has an output of: 4, 11, 14, 16 which is not what I want as its considering each character separately but I want it to consider '.E' as one that is if an E comes after a dot then it should consider it as one. if this should be ran considering the '.E' as failure, the expected output should be 3, 9, 11, 12. Thanks :)

Comment: if i understood right, you are looking for the text `.E`. In that case you could use `secondLine.indexOf(".E", i)`

Comment: Why does it *add* the E to the dot, instead of *replacing* it?

Comment: Can you please modify your question? It is hard to understand your question. I think secondLine.indexOf(".E", i) must work.

Comment: @Narkha I have done as you suggested but it works for just the first '.E' in the string and treats the others as a single character. This was my output after the change: 3, 10,13,15

Comment: @Tom Because the E next to the dot shows that the test was failed for the dot before it.

Comment: @Buzz And what tells you that? You still don't know which test it was, so where is the point (:D) in keeping that dot? A single *E* tells you the exact same thing as *.E*. It just making it harder for you to analyze the results (this questions proves it).

Comment: @Tom this is ran by junit! and this is contained in a secondLine in a txt file. if a submission is made withouth a failure then it is '............' = 12. and any failures it adds an E in front of the dot :))))

Comment: @Buzz You already wrote that ... three times. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Buzz Let's assume you have 3 Test. If all succeed, you will get `...`. If one fails, you might get `.E..` and if all fails, you'll get `.E.E.E`. And now I wonder why you *add* the `E` to the dot, instead of *replacing* the dot with the E. The dot itself won't tell you anything, it just increase the length of the test result, nothing more. So it would make much more sense to get results like `...`, `E..` or `EEE` and it would make it much easier to analyze that, because you have to look for a single `E` instead of `.E`.

Comment: @Tom Yeah that makes perfect sense. I thought of that but just thought it would be harder as I am quite a novice programmer. would yoy know how to do that then? :)

Comment: @Buzz Well, somewhere in your code you'll have to print either `.` or `.E`. Find that place and remove the dot in front of the `E`. Or if you use some kind of library to print the test results, then check its documentation to find a way to change the output.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem better now: if i am right, you print a `.`, ran the test and if it do not pass, you will print an `E`.

The point if the final length of `secondLine` is the number of test plus the number of error, so the if the first error is the test T-i, the T-i dot would be at the position T-i, its `E` would be at the position (T-1) + 1. The following test would be displaced one position: the dot of the test T-(i+1) would be at the position (T-i) + 2. Do you see the point?

So, this is my suggestion

```
String secondLine = "...E......E..E.E";    
String failures = "E";    
String passed = ".";

int detectedErrors = 0;
int i = 0;
while ((i = (secondLine.indexOf(failures, i) + 1)) > 0) {
    System.out.println(i);
    feedbackString += "<strong style='color: red;'><li>Failed: </strong><strong>" 
                    + (i - detectedErrors) // here
                    + "</strong> - " + "out of " + resultString.length() + " tests.<br>";
    detectedErrors += 1; // and here
}
```

Comment: Currently he prints `.E` if a test fails.

Comment: Well, at the end the result is the same `.` if the test pass and `.E` if it not.
But maybe would be more clear print only  `E` instead of  `.E` .

Comment: I know, I told him that already :D. We will see if he is possible to do that.

Comment: I tried your code but couldnt get it to work because I have a bad operand error around '+ i - detectedErrors ' with the minus sign

Comment: @Buzz change `i - detectedErrors` to `(i - detectedErrors)`

Comment: @Narkha do you know how I can return the remainder of the dots showing the passed test? and the resultString :)) thanks

Comment: @Buzz sorry, i do not understantd your question? could you give me an example?

Comment: It's fine now as I've sorted all of it. Thanks for your help man I truly appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the number of extra characters in the secondLine and subtract them from the match position.  Also change your failure String to ".E"

```
    String secondLine = "...E......E..E.E";
    String failures = ".E";
    String passed = ".";
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while ((i = (secondLine.indexOf(failures, i) + 1)) > 0) {
        System.out.println(i-n);
        n++;
        feedbackString += "<strong style='color: red;'><li>Failed: </strong><strong>" + (i-n) + "</strong> - " + "out of " + resultString.length() + " tests.<br>";
```

Comment: Hey man, I was wondering how you could add your output from this code as EEEE instead of 3,9,11 and 12?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  BTW I think a simpler approach is just to transform the string into a single character for a pass and a single character for a fail.  `secondLine.replaceAll("\\.E", "F").replaceAll("\\.", "P")` will give you a simple string `"PPFPPPPPFPFF"`.